# How to construct Goldstone bosons from a conserved charge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

The Goldstone boson associated with a conserved charge is described by
$$
|\pi(\vec p)\rangle\propto \int d^3x~e^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}j_0(x)|0\rangle.
$$
How can I see that this is a state with energy given by $E_0+E(\vec p)$ and momentum $\vec p$, namely a one-particle state? Is it for instance possible to use the Hamilton operator in order to check that the given state has the energy $E_0+E(\vec p)$ (and the momentum operator in order check that the state has momentum $\vec{p}$)?

Comment: Schwartz, your text whose (28.8) you are quoting, has reviewed all in his preceding section. Note $\pi(p)$ is *not* the canonical momentum, but, instead, $\phi(p)$, the pion field itself, and $J_0(x)\propto F\partial_0 \phi(x)$, and its commutation with *H* yields a time derivative, so $\sim F \nabla \cdot \vec {\mathbf J}(x)\sim F\nabla^2 \phi(x)$...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the following derivation:
Expand $j_0(x)$ as 
$$
j_0(x)=\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}f(k)a_{\vec k}^\dagger e^{-\vec k\cdot x}$$
where I didn't write the $a_{\vec k}$ term since they annihilate the vacuum. And using $H\sim\int d^3 k\omega_{\vec k}a_{\vec k}a_{\vec k}^\dagger$ we can arrive at the result.
Is my derivation correct?

Comment: It should be, to the extent the current here is ***linear*** in the pion field; it's not a deep point: most QFT texts such as Schwarz's, evidently yours, cover it in the review of current algebra manipulations...